# Should I wait for my company's IPO to go through?

Tags: company-culture, stock

I'm working for a +20,000 person company with 3 years in a mid-level position. I do not manage but I'm instrumental to the team's functions — I received a rather large bonus last year despite 2020 and revenue throughout the organization being difficult. The company is in the process of doing an IPO, though I'm uncertain what the time frame is. Cutting a long story short, I'm considering leaving the company.

Should I wait for the IPO to go through? Is there usually any stock offering to employees or any similar benefits? I cannot ask my manager since it's an obvious clue to my intentions.

Comment: Do you already have stock options?

Comment: No stock options currently -- no information released either

Comment: If you don’t already have stock/options, and it hasn’t been mentioned as a possibility, then it is unlikely that there’s going to be any.

Comment: You will also have to keep in mind, even if they were to offer you stock options, it might be conditional stock that takes time to mature (vesting).

Comment: As Donald says it is inconceivable to get "stock as such", you'd get essentially stock once you proved you stayed working there for some years (say, 4) after the IPO.  But, very unfortunately, it appears they have given the OP nothing.

Comment: @Fattie - It’s not unheard of, not everyone at Facebook, got stock before their IPO but today it’s more common.

Comment: @Donald just to be clear what I meant was:  it's inconceivable you'll get *stock as such*, you will get some form of options.  (Or other instrument where the mechanism is "You get stock after such and such years of dedication from this point forward.)

Comment: Just TBC Donald what I meant is.  You see where you wrote *it **might** be conditional .. that takes time to mature*.  That is like saying the sun might rise tomorrow, politicians might lie, and hookers might charge you money  :) :)  Yes, apart from anything else, if the  OP gets "stock" it will be something that only vests years and years from now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Should I wait for the IPO to go through? Is there usually any stock offering to employees or any similar benefits? I cannot ask my manager since it's an obvious clue to my intentions.

If the company awarded private stock it would have a vesting period when they would give you stock as part of your overall compensation.  Usually you'd be awarded stock once a year.  If they have not done this there is no reason to wait for IPO, it likely won't affect you very much.

> Cutting a long story short, I'm considering leaving the company.

Start looking.  It doesn't sound like there will be a wind-fall for you if the company does go public.

Comment: Unfortunately, sounds about right. Curiously asking: are you recalling from experience or referencing a source?

Comment: @ipo-q Experience and war stories.

Comment: Yeah, if you *have* vested options then an IPO can be great for you, but they don’t just come around and give out money otherwise.

Comment: This is a pragmatic answer

Comment: @ipo-q options are awarded when the company is young to entice people to stay.  The pay is typically lower and the pace brutal.  The only reason to stay is the payout at IPO.  I have never heard of a company offering options as they approach IPO.  Well prior, yes.  After, yes.  Although those offered after IPO tend to be worth much less.

Comment: My IPO after five years with the startup, was just about enough cash to buy a new mid range car.  All my options were offered as part of my hiring agreement, and the stock wasn't traded enough to get shares many other ways.  If you don't have stock in the company before it goes IPO, you're not part of that party (and will require someone else to give up their chance at a windfall to join it, so you're not going to be part of that party either).

Answer (score 4):

> I cannot ask my manager since it's an obvious clue to my intentions.

No, you absolutely need to ask! Your bosses are potentially about to earn hundreds of millions. Now is not the time to be shy.

If they don't know you're unhappy, they're not going to offer you anything. Ask if there is going to be a retention package, or if you will be getting stock options. If anything, asking signals to your company that you intend to stay for the long-run. Only an employee who's about to leave wouldn't be interested in these extremely important questions.

When DoorDash hired software developers during their pre-IPO period (when their IPO was already on the horizon), they felt pressured to offer all the newly hired software developers [Restricted Stock Unit Options](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/restricted-stock-unit.asp) (RSUs). This is because nobody who's any good wants to join a company who's about to IPO without getting in on some of the action.

So you need to do some [research](https://www.levels.fyi/) and find out if the new employees at your company are getting the same kind of deal. It would be a real shame if the new hires were getting such a deal, and you were not.

Now, will those Stock Options come in the form of golden handcuffs? Well, yes, that's pretty much standard. But then, you can make your decision to leave with all the information in hand at least. And right now, it wouldn't hurt to explore all your options by raising the Stock Options issue with your manager and anyone else with authority that might listen and still look for a job elsewhere to see what kind of offers you can get on the open market.

And if you do get offered RSUs, and if another company makes you a good offer, then you tell them: "I really like you guys, and I would absolutely love to work here! But I'm leaving some RSUs on the table if I leave my current employer now. Can you speak to your higher-ups and see if you can offer some similar terms?"

Comment: An excellent answer ...

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, asking the manager about stocks for employees would not be a clue of your intentions if you have no stock currently

It would be a display of prudent financial interest on your part, given the IPO

Answer (score -9):

You've been screwed.

What I would do is "one more chance"...

In a word: just plain demand that you want shares and/or options right now, and you want a lot of them.

- Do this in private
- Do it to the parties who can make actual decisions.  (People like "team leads" or "your boss" are a waste of space in this issue.)
- Make it a flat but polite ultimatum.  Essentially ...

> Hi guys. As you know from my incredible work here, I deserve a substantial position, which will be worth $X on the market when my tranche vests some years from now. Because of my dedication and faithfulness to the company, this is a must. Unfortunately for me, without this I'll be leaving.

If they don't promptly satisfy you, leave.

Very unfortunately, this is all you can do ... now.

Best of luck.

Note that for folks who do *not* have options/shares in a company which IPOs, the IPO is a disaster.

Comment: It doesn't sound the author is high enough in the food chain to demand anything like you suggest (based on the fact they are not management).

Comment: Unfortunately then they should just leave.

Comment: Is this answer meant to be sarcastic given how outrageous it is?

Comment: @Anthony, No, that is usually how Fattie answers all questions. And he isn't usually sarcastic.

Comment: @Anthony - just curious, why is it "outrageous"?  It is totally normal that employees before an IPO say "I want options or I am leaving".  This is a completely everyday thing.

Comment: I've worked at a number of places that have exited and demanding huge amounts of stock vested in the immediate future has never been something anyone would consider saying yes to. You can have asked for options when you started or 1+ years ago such that they're vested, or you can say you want RSUs or whatnot that begin to vest in the new regime, but this is just "write me a 7 figure check or I leave" and unless you are a CEO type the answer will be "don't let the door hit you in the ass on the way out."

Comment: @mxyzplk , exactly I said "stock position that vests in the future" rather than "options" since OP is not clear on that.  in short the OP needs to get options (or whatever instrument) now, or leave. I clarified.